# How can I compute the error function of a Monte Carlo algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, probability, montecarlo

> Two  sets  of  integers A and B of  size k≥2 are given such that, either, A∩B=∅ , or A∩B is the singleton{s} and s = max A = max B.

We have the following algorithm that determines if max A = max B:

```
pick at random a1∈A, a2∈A, b1∈B, b2∈B 
if max{a1, a2}= max{b1, b2}
   return TRUE
else
   return FALSE
```

Now I'm told to compute as a function of k the error probability of this algorithm. I have absolutely no idea how to do this. It would be nice if someone could give me hints to get unstuck.

Comment: why not just execute `return max{a1, a2} = max(b1, b2}`?

Comment: because it's a Monte Carlo algorithm. It must say if the answer given is correct or not. A Monte Carlo algorithm must always return an answer.

Comment: What are the probabilities of the two cases (empty intersection versus non-empty intersection)?

Comment: it is not provided so I assume it's random.